# Apple Script for autotyping

Tags: applescript, xcode

I'd just like to know how to add multiple lines in my autotyper.

Currently, all that it can do is repeat the same lines over and over again, which is "NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE".

I'd like to find out how to add multiple different lines of text, then for the lines to repeat.

Here is my current code:

```
tell application "System Events"
delay 1
set textToType to "NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE"
    repeat
        delay 5
        keystroke textToType
        keystroke return
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Can't you just define several variables and output them all within the loop?

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely must do it by AppleScript, the simplest way is just to concatenate your textToType with ready-inserted returns.
If you copy/paste multi-line text, AppleScript will insert new line characters `\n` but these don't actually translate well in other apps

```
set textToType to "NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE" & return & "Notice 2" & return & ¬  
"Notice 3" & return & "Notice 4" & return
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke textToType
end tell
```

The little 'sideways L' ¬ just tells Applescript that this new line is not a new script line but a continuation of the previous one - so it doesn't scroll right off the page.

Without it the line would look like this

```
set textToType to "NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE" & return & "Notice 2" & return & "Notice 3" & return & Notice 4" & return
```

---

Personally, this is the kind of task I would give to Apple's built-in text replacement function rather than AppleScript.

System Prefs > Keyboard > Text

Hit + at the bottom, type in your trigger word, then copy/paste from something like TextEdit, which will correctly keep your carriage returns.
[You cannot add carriage returns directly in that pref pane, you have to copy/paste an existing source. You also cannot see a multi-line replacement correctly in the pane - but it will be exactly as you copied it, in use.]

Then, every time you type your trigger, it will replace it with your multi-line paste.

[image]

---

After comments - if you need a delay between each line, then you cannot concatenate & must send each call separately

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE" & return
    delay 5
    keystroke "Notice 2" & return
    delay 5
    keystroke "Notice 3" & return
    delay 5
    keystroke "Notice 4" & return
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Although, how do I add a delay before the new line of text?

Comment: If you need a delay, you can't concatenate, see addition to answer.